# Dialogs are not being updated in AEM 6.3

Tags: java, xml, aem

Hi I am facing an issue in AEM 6.3, after doing some changes in our code, the author dialogs are not being updated after the build is done, every other code is succesfully updated (JS, CSS) but only dialogs (XML) are not being updated in CRXDE.

Please let me know if someone has face with this issue and if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Check if there are any errors when the package is getting installed. Most probably there might be issues in the XML due to which that alone would have skipped. You can just try reinstalling the same code package in CRX Package Manager and look at the console below for any messages.

Comment: Did you change any `filter.xml` files recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that I was doing the build with a component who only had two xmls (the dialog for touch UI and the other for classic UI), it was necessary to add the content.xml.